# JOOQ: How to best access columns polymorphically?

Tags: polymorphism, jooq

Our scenario is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52524694/8707976). We have tables that are "deletable", meaning they have an additional set of columns related to deletion, such as "DELETED", "DELETED_BY" etc. Now what we'd like to do is:

```
dsl.select()
  .from(CUSTOMER)
  .where(createDeletedCondition(CUSTOMER, currentUserId))
```

with `createDeletedCondition` being a method that can be applied to all deletable tables:

```
public static Condidtion createDeletedCondition(final IDeletableTable deletableTable, final UUID currentUserId) {
  return deletableTable.DELETED.isTrue().and(deletableTable.DELETED_BY.eq(currentUserId));
}
```

Right now we're accessing the fields by explicitly naming them (`deletableTable.getField("deleted_by")`), which seems awkward and not safe against refactorings. Maybe there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Adding API to generated code

The question is slightly different from the [one you've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52524694/521799), as the other question intends to add stuff to generated *records*, whereas yours wants to add stuff to generated *tables*. But the mechanism is the same. You can define an interface:

```java
public interface IDeletableTable {
    Field<Boolean> DELETED();
    Field<UUID> DELETED_BY();
}
```

And then, extend the generated code

- [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52524694/521799)
- [configuratively](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/)

A configurative example:

```xml
..
<generator>
  <strategy>
    <matchers>
      <tables>
        <table>
          <expression>MY_TABLE</expression>
          <tableImplements>com.example.IDeletableTable</tableImplements>
        </table>
      </tables>
    </matchers>
  </strategy>
</generator>
```

And then, provide [the custom code section](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/) to implement the interface:

```java
// A programmatic
public class MyJavaGenerator extends JavaGenerator {

    @Override
    public void generateTableClassFooter(TableDefinition table, JavaWriter out) {
        // Repeat the generator strategy's expression:
        if (table.getInputName().matches("MY_TABLE")) {

            // Take inspiration for these things from JavaGenerator::generateTable
            // It's also possible to hardcode things or otherwise avoid internal codegen
            // API. For example, out.ref() is only used to generate an import for types,
            // which may already be imported.
            String columnTypeFull = getJavaType(column.getType(resolver()));
            String columnType = out.ref(columnTypeFull);
            String columnId = out.ref(getStrategy().getJavaIdentifier(column), 3);

            out.javadoc("...");
            out.override();
            out.println("public %s<%s> %s() {", Field.class, columnType, columnId);
            out.println("    return %s;");
            out.println("}");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code uses some formatting tools available only from jOOQ 3.14, to simplify indentation. You can indent things manually, of course.

#### Using embeddable types

For a while, jOOQ had an undocumented (and moving target) feature called embeddable types, which has a good chance to be finalised in the upcoming jOOQ 3.14:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/projects/15
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2530

With embeddable types, you can extract a new data type that wrapps the two fields in one compound field (similar to JPA's `@Embeddable` types) and allows for reusing the shared data type across tables. This way, you could simply pass around a table's `TableField<DeletionInfo>`, regarless of what table the embeddable type is contained in.

I will update this answer once the feature is stable in 3.14.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! As I understand, the proposed solution would require a (Gradle) subproject containing the custom generator Java class, which I cannot introduce into our project at this point. I was hoping to do this configuration-only, but I guess I'll have to stick with hardcoded field names for now. The embeddable type solution sounds awesome!

Comment: @Sebastian: You can use `default` methods in your interfaces, which use the string based version...

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I decided as well:
  `default Field<Boolean> DELETED() {
    return field("deleted", Boolean.class);
  }`

Comment: @LukasEder In your answer, you write "I will update this answer once the feature is stable in 3.14", now that JOOQ 3.14 is released, you might want to update your answer?

Comment: @Theo: Yeah, I'll put it on my TODO list, thanks for the ping. I have a large TODO list, though, so you'd be much faster playing around with the feature directly: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-embeddable-types/, and possibly offering your own answer here...?